# Accessing IIS Localhost from Selenium docker container

Tags: c#, .net, selenium, docker, iis

I have a .net application running on my windows machine on local host. I have also set up a selenium docker container using this command:

```
docker run -d -p 4444:4444 -v /dev/shm:/dev/shm selenium/standalone-chrome
```

I can access the container fine by pointing the remote webdriver to localhost:4444

However when I run a test and tell the webdriver to navigate to "http://docker.for.win.localhost:51749" I get a connection refused error in the screenshot.

I've looked at similar questions but they were using different technologies and those solutions didn't work for me so I figured my problem might be slightly different as my website is running in IIS express in visual studio.

I have tried to SSH to the container and do a WGET on the same address and that ends up yielding a 400 error as shown below.

```
seluser@832dfa5515d6:/$ wget docker.for.win.localhost:51749
--2019-05-24 12:45:45--  http://docker.for.win.localhost:51749/
Resolving docker.for.win.localhost (docker.for.win.localhost)... 192.168.65.2
Connecting to docker.for.win.localhost (docker.for.win.localhost)|192.168.65.2|:51749... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 400 Bad Request
2019-05-24 12:45:45 ERROR 400: Bad Request.
```

What could be the cause of this issue?

I am using Docker Desktop with engine 18.09.2 which is running on windows (although I believe the inside of the container is linux)

UPDATE

I just tried:

```
 curl -i -X GET -H "Host: localhost:51749" docker.for.win.localhost:51749
```

This ends up returning the HTML of the site. So it seems the container can actually see it... just selenium cant.